# Express: Is it possible to simplify the path in res.sendFile?

Tags: node.js, express, static-files

This is my directory structure:
/Users/titi/myproject/app/server/
....app.js
..../public
......../css
......../js
......../view
............index.html
............about.html

---

And my app.js file:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.use(express.static('public'));

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
   res.sendFile('/Users/Titi/myproject/app/server/public/view/index.html');
});

app.get('/about', function (req, res) {
   res.sendFile('/Users/Titi/myproject/app/server/public/view/about.html');
});

app.listen(2000, function () {
  console.log('Example app listening on port 2000!');
});
```

It works perfectly.
But I would like to know if there is a way to not have to write the whole path (/Users/Titi/myproject/app/server/public/view/about.html).
Is it possible to simplify?

Comment: The [`path`](https://nodejs.org/api/path.html) module will probably be of use to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could specify a `root` path in the `sendFile()` options:

```
var viewOpts = { root: '/Users/Titi/myproject/app/server/public/view' };
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.sendFile('index.html', viewOpts);
});
```

*Or* you could use the built-in `path` to make the absolute path for you:

```
var path = require('path');

// Assuming this script is inside the `server` portion of the path

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.resolve('public/view/index.html'));
});
```

Comment: The `path` this is realy helpfull if the application has to run in different  environments

Answer (score 0):

You can create a variable and store that path in that.

```
const tmpldir = '/Users/Titi/myproject/app/server/public;

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.sendFile(`${tmpldir}/index.html`);
});
```

Note: Ideally you should be using `router` instead of `app`;

Answer (score 0):

Set the view folder and view engine
install ejs template `npm install ejs` but you need to change `sendFile`

```
app.set('views', '/Users/Titi/myproject/app/server/public/view');
app.set('view engine', 'html');
app.engine('.html', require('ejs').renderFile);

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
   res.render('index');
});
```

if you still want to use `sendFile` you need specify the absolute path